# Error con múltiple llave foránea al mismo modelo en Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Necesito que me ayuden por favor con un error que me sale, he intentado poner los `related_names` pero sigue saliendo el mismo error. (uso Django 1.6.5 y Python 2.7)

Error:

[image: error1]

Mis modelos:

```
class Novedad(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="persona")
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="responsable")
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area) # área de ocurrencia de la novedad
    cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo) # cargo ejercido el dia de la novedad
    sucursal = models.ForeignKey(Sucursal)
    fecha_diligenciamiento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AusentismoBase(Novedad):
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha Inicial")
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha Final")
    mes = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    quincena = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    hora_inicio = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Hora Inicial", blank=True, null=True)
    hora_fin = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Hora Final", blank=True, null=True)
    motivo = models.IntegerField(choices=MOTIVOS_AUSENTISMO, verbose_name="Tipo de Ausentismo")
    eps = models.ForeignKey(Eps)
    arl = models.ForeignKey(Arl)
    edad = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    salario = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    #jornada = models.IntegerField(choices=JORNADAS, verbose_name="Jornada")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"Ausentismo %s: %s - %s)"%(self.persona, self.motivo, self.fecha_inicio)).strip() or "-"


class Reintegro(Novedad):
    area_seleccionada = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name="area_seleccionadaR", verbose_name="nueva área seleccionada")
    cargo_seleccionado = models.ForeignKey(Cargo, related_name="cargo_seleccionadoR", verbose_name="nuevo cargo seleccionado")
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField()
    tipo_empleado = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIPO_EMPLEADO)
```

Mi único formulario (por ahora):

```
class AusentismoBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AusentismoBase
        exclude = ('persona', 'responsable', 'area', 'cargo', 'sucursal', 'mes', 'quincena', 'eps', 'arl', 'edad', 'salario')
        widgets = {
            'municipio': Select2Widget(),
            'fecha_inicio' : MyDateWidget(),
            'fecha_fin' : MyDateWidget(),
            'hora_inicio': TimeWidget(usel10n=False, bootstrap_version=3),
            'hora_fin': TimeWidget(usel10n=False, bootstrap_version=3),

            #'soporte' : MyFileInput(),
            'observaciones': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 30, 'rows': 2}),
        }
```

Mi única vista (por ahora):

```
def crear_ausentismo(request, idPersona=None):
    persona = None
    hoy = datetime.now()

    form = AusentismoBaseForm()    
    form2 = CedulaForm(request.POST)

    if(idPersona):
        persona = Persona.objects.get(id=idPersona)
        form = AusentismoBaseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("dió clic")
            objeto = form.save(commit=False)

            objeto.persona = persona
            objeto.responsable = Persona.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
            objeto.area = persona.cargo.area
            objeto.cargo = persona.cargo
            objeto.sucursal = persona.sucursal
            objeto.mes = hoy.month
            if hoy.day >= 16:
                objeto.quincena = 2
            else:
                objeto.quincena = 1
                objeto.eps = persona.eps
                objeto.arl = persona.arl
                objeto.edad = edad(persona)
                objeto.salario = persona.salario

            objeto.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect('crear_ausentismo', persona.id)
        else:
            print("aún no da clic")
            form = AusentismoBaseForm()
            form2 = CedulaForm()
    else:
        if form2.is_valid():
            persona = form2.cleaned_data['persona']
            return redirect('crear_ausentismo', persona.id)
        else:
            try:
                form2 = CedulaForm({'persona': persona.id})
            except Exception:
                form2 = CedulaForm()

    return render(request, 'ausentismo.html', {
        'persona': persona,
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
        'hoy': hoy,
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tanto `AusentismoBase` como `Reintegro` están usando el mismo `related_name` para los campos `persona` y `responsable` pero este es el comportamiento esperado ya que es una clase abstracta.

Para resolverlo puedes modificar los `related_name` de tu clase abstracta para que contengan el nombre de la clase que la hereda:

```
class Novedad(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="%(class)s_persona")
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="%(class)s_responsable")
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area) 
    cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo) 
    sucursal = models.ForeignKey(Sucursal)
    fecha_diligenciamiento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Por lo tanto, ahora los queries inversos para una instancia de `Persona` serían.

1. Para el campo `persona`:

   ```
   >>> persona.ausentismobase_persona.all()
   >>> persona.reintegro_persona.all()
   ```
2. Para el campo `responsable`:

   ```
   >>> persona.ausentismobase_responsable.all()
   >>> persona.reintegro_responsable.all()
   ```

Comment: Esto cómo cambia mi view? (objeto.persona y objeto.responsable) Y mi form? (los exclude). Quiero que me expliques la relación entre el related_name y verbose_name

Comment: Hola @César, ¿que es de tu vida? estas desaparecido!! ... saludos

Comment: @rnd mi hermano, ando con mucho trabajo. Pronto estaré de vuelta, saludos a todos!