# ¿Cómo relacionar un Objeto con otro en varios campos?

Tags: python, django

Estoy empezando a desarrollar una web app desde **Django**. Hasta ahora he desarrollado utilizando phpmyadmin y php, por lo tanto no necesitaba plantearme este tipo de problemas.

Normalmente utilizo una estructura tal cual esta, para trabajar las traducciones:

```
TABLA idiomas {
   id_idioma = identificador para referenciar el idioma
   slug = cadena para identificarlo visualmente
}
TABLA traduccion_idiomas {
  id_origen = referencia al id del idioma del que quiero traducir
  id_destino = referencia al id del idioma al que quiero realizar la traducción
  texto = valor traducido
}
```

De este modo podía referenciar en el campo `id_origen` al `id_idioma` de la tabla "idiomas" a la vez que el campo `id_destino` para crear así una traducción.

En Django:

```
class Idioma(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class TraduccionIdioma(models.Model):
    origen = ForeignKey(Idioma)
    destino = ForeignKey(Idioma)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Esta sintaxis me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
biblioteca.TraduccionIdioma.destino: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'TraduccionIdioma.destino' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TraduccionIdioma.origen'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TraduccionIdioma.destino' or 'TraduccionIdioma.origen'.
 biblioteca.TraduccionIdioma.origen: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'TraduccionIdioma.origen' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TraduccionIdioma.destino'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TraduccionIdioma.origen' or 'TraduccionIdioma.destino'.
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? No sé qué relaciones he de utilizar para éste caso.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11561

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu problema como dice claramente el error es que tienes `related_name` idéntico, por defecto si no lo seteas Django asigna el por defecto y por lo tanto aparece duplicado al querer crear la tabla por lo que simplemente deberías modificar el modelo así:

```
class TraduccionIdioma(models.Model):
     origen = ForeignKey(Idioma, related_name='origen')
     destino = ForeignKey(Idioma, related_name='destion')
     value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

puedes ver información sobre [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) en la documentación de [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!